# line break inside <p> tags when using Jquery.text()

Tags: jquery, html, jquery-ui

I am trying to do something like this:

`<p> Line 1 <br/> Line 2 <br/> </p>`

This does not work, but is what i'm trying to do possible?

Edit: more info

i am executing this line of code: `$("#textDialogBox").text("test<br />test2");`

where `#textDialogBox` is `<p id = "textDialogBox">This is an animated dialog which is useful for displaying information. The dialog window can be moved, resized and closed with the 'x' icon.</p>`

But when I open the dialog box the 
 shows up as text, rather than a line break.

Comment: Define "does not work". This should work fine (introducing line breaks after Line 1 and Line 2.

Comment: This should work fine, although in some older browsers, you might need to do `<br />` (notice the space before the slash)

Comment: sorry, i thought the issue was with the html, maybe it is not. I'm posting more info now.

Comment: added more info and changed my tags as this seems to have something to do with jquery

Answer (score 57, accepted):

Have this instead:

```
$("#textDialogBox").html("test<br/>test2");
```

The text() method of jQuery will "destroy" any HTML given to it, and this includes `<br />` as well.